# Struts2 forms following progressive enhancement to work without AJAX

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am reworking my forms so that they will work without javascript enabled but also work well with javascript by using jquery and AJAX. I am using struts which has proven to be both helpful and a pain. The form processing without javascript was handled with basic struts functionality by validating and executing the action and dispatching back to the page the user was on but with the result (actionMessage or actionError) set in the forms html. I had a hidden input with the url of the page which would be set in the form bean, and that is the dispatch location in the struts.xml

My problem is that I need to be able to have this functionality underneath some enhanced functionality such as JSON serialization and AJAX requests, and I can't figure out a way to have both. Below are my configurations and code for the no-script form which works fine.

**The struts.xml file**

```
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default">
        <action name="contact" class="org.deadmandungeons.website.action.ContactAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">%{currentPage}</result>
            <result name="input">%{currentPage}</result>
            <result name="error">%{currentPage}</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**The No-script JSP**

```
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' prefix='c'%>
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<s:form id="contact_form" action="contact" method="post" cssClass="clearfix">
    <label for="contact_user">Username / In-game name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="contact_user" name="contactBean.username"
        class="field" data-enter-click="sendbutton" maxlength="16"
        size="16" />
    <label for="contact_email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="contact_email" name="contactBean.email" class="field" data-enter-click="sendbutton" />
    <label for="contact_message">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="contact_message" name="contactBean.message" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea>
    <input id="no_script" name="contactBean.currentPage" type="hidden" value="${pageContext.request.requestURL}" />
    <div id="contact_response" class="response">
        <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
            <s:actionerror id="contact_fail" cssClass="fail" />
        </s:if>
        <s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
            <s:actionmessage id="contact_success" cssClass="success" />
        </s:if>
    </div>
    <s:submit type="submit" id="sendbutton" value="Send" />
</s:form>
```

The contactAction class is just a basic action class holding a ContactBean for the necessary fields, and adding ActionErrors when it doesnt validate or ActionMessages on success.

Now for the jquery AJAX approach on top of this, I have tried a couple things. I have the struts2 jquery plugin installed which is a great plugin, and I am able to get ajax working fin on forms with it, but not with the way my struts configuration is in the example above. For the dispatch location for the result in struts.xml, I had it set to a jsp page that looks like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<s:property value="response" escapeHtml="false"/>
```

and I added a field called response to the action class which was just set with the actionError or actionMessage strings. The jquery plugin was able to take the result from that jsp, and append it to the target locations fine. But that means that if I do the same with javascript turned of, once the form is submited, the user would be dispatched to that jsp which only displays the result string rather than dispatching them to the same page and setting the message in the form.

I have also tried to use the struts2 json plugin (which is also great), but this also only works well with jquery ajax, and not when there is no javascript.

Any ideas on how to get a form to work in both settings? 
Thanks!

Comment: The code doesn't use the javascript, it's not the same if the javascript turned off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of struts interceptors. I made a custom interceptor that would check the stack parameters if a 'noScript' parameter existed, and if it did, It would return a result of 'noScript'. The noScript result is of type 'chain' and would then forward to the action that handles the form response when there is no javascript. The noScript parameter is set through a hidden field in the form that has the url of the current page. when the page loads, jquery will remove this input anywhere on the page. So if javascript is disabled, the noScript input will not be removed. Here is my new struts.xml after:

```
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="noScriptInterceptor"
                class="org.deadmandungeons.website.NoScriptInterceptor"></interceptor>

            <interceptor-stack name="noScriptStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="noScriptInterceptor" />
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <action name="contact" class="org.deadmandungeons.website.action.ContactAction" method="execute">
            <interceptor-ref name="noScriptStack"/>
            <result type="json" name="success" />
            <result type="json" name="input" />
            <result type="json" name="error"/>
            <result type="chain" name="noScript">noScriptContact</result>
        </action>

        <action name="noScriptContact" class="org.deadmandungeons.website.action.ContactAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">%{noScript}</result>
            <result name="input">%{noScript}</result>
            <result name="error">%{noScript}</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

And here is the NoScriptInterceptor class:

```
public class NoScriptInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1472114260682759961L;

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        final ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext();

        String actionName = Utils.toCamelCase(invocation.getAction().getClass().getName());

        Map<String,Object> parameters = (Map<String,Object>)context.get(ActionContext.PARAMETERS);

        Object noScriptParam = parameters.get(actionName + ".noScript");
        if (noScriptParam != null) {
            return Constants.NO_SCRIPT;
        }

        return invocation.invoke();
    }

}
```

Comment: What you will do if the action executed first?

Comment: @RomanC Why would the action execute first? I am invoking the action when returning, and I do the noscript checking logic before invoking.

Comment: yes, but normal logic is to invoke an action on upcoming request, then return a result. However, it doesn't concern your usecase if you won't intercept some actions without `noScript` parameter.